# Salesforce.com - Why uploading of Apex class is not working?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, force.com

I have an Apex class (controller) originally developed under Developer Edition and need to upload it to production which is Enterprise Edition.

The upload fails with following message

```
classes/RenewalController.cls(RenewalController):An error occurred on your page.

package.xml(RenewalController):An object 'RenewalController' of type ApexClass 
was named in manifest but was not found in zipped directory
```

The same message when I try to use Force.com IDE: *Save error: An error occurred on your page.*

This class is working under Developer Edition but not with Enterprise.

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller class may reference other custom SalesForce objects like pages. If controller is uploaded before these objects *Save error: An error occurred on your page.* is reported.

Correct order of uploading of custom components should be used.

Answer (score 3):

Dmytro, you are correct. Visualforce pages, apex classes, and components must be uploaded in the correct order. Generally the pattern I use is upload the controllers, components, and then visualforce pages.